# Why Apache IoTDB prompt `frame size (707923210) larger than protect max size (536870912)` error?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

The error information of my Apache IoTDB server is `ERROR o.a.t.s.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess: 258 - Thrift Error occured during processing of message. org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (707923210) larger than protect max size (536870912).`  I cannot understand this message, so does anyone know where should I start to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that the size of your write request in Apache IoTDB exceeds 500MB. The data written at one time is too large. You can try to find the problem of your data writing progress.